# Use inherit class for instance List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, design-patterns, ilist

Hello stackoverflow community!

Let's start!

I have one small class `Person`:

```
class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Аnd it has a descendant `Employee`:

```
class Employee : Person
{
    public int salary { get; set; }
}
```

And second descendant is `Guest`:

```
class Guest: Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Ok! looks good :)

Now I want to display a list of all employees ***OR*** guests in a single control `ListView`

I made a class (it really necessary) for list management `PeopleList`:

```
class PeopleList
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    ...

    public void LoadListFromFile()
    {
        // Load logic

        this.People = new List<?>(source);
    }
}
```

Do you see this question mark? No? Look at the code again!

How to create an instance of `List` that I can use my class something like this:

```
// This instance with the list of Person objects
PeopleList list = new PeopleList();

foreach (Employee e in list.People)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.salary.toString());
}

// This instance with the list of Guest objects
PeopleList list = new PeopleList();

foreach (Guest g in list.People)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(g.id.toString());
}
```

*P.S. I'm new in c# and I think that I have a problem in architecture. And maybe you point me to the pattern solves my problem. I really need your help! Thank you!*

Comment: What's wrong here? you should fill in the `?` the class name `Person`.

Comment: What's wrong with doing `this.People = new List<People>(source);`?

Comment: I would be so hyped up to answer this, but it's just as the previous comments said. Bummer.

Comment: If I do that I can not have access to the properties of class `Employee` and `Guest` because it will be list of `Person` objects

Comment: @Stmol: You can cast the Person object to the respective child class before accessing required properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're after `OfType`, in the `System.Linq` library:

```
foreach (Employee e in personList.OfType<Employee>())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.salary.toString());
}
foreach (Guest g in personList.OfType<Guest>())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(g.id.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only field in Person that is shared with all of the decedents is the field 'name', therefore, if you are casting each item in your list to Person you will only have access to 'name'.

You have a few options to solve this issue.  1) you could move all of the common fields into the base class, but this is probably not want since it defeats the point of an object hierarchy, or 2) you can type check, using the [**"Is" keyword**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), each person in the list so see what type of person it is and then [**cast**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) that Person to the appropriate decedent class before you operate on it.

For example:

```
foreach (Person p in list.People)
{
    if(p is Employee)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(((Employee)p).salary.toString());
    }

    if(p is Guest)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(((Guest)p).Id.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is an alternate more clear way of casting

```
foreach (Person p in list.People)
{
    if(p is Employee)
    {
      Employee employee = p as Employee;

      Debug.WriteLine(employee.salary.toString());
    }

    if(p is Guest)
    {
      Guest guest = p as Guest;     

      Debug.WriteLine(guest.Id.toString());
    }
```

}

Additionally you can learn more about type checking using the "is" keyword [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Also just for clarity, since it might not be obvious, some others have suggested that you use OfType in linq but this more of a way to filter like object from a list of mixed objects as opposed to actually type checking each one.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey Doug, is that valid C#? Ive never added the cast at the end before. Interesting.

Comment: yes its a short hand way of casting.  Ill add another clearer way for you too.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments are saying, you can do the following;

```
public void LoadListFromFile()
{
    // Load logic

    this.People = new List<Person>(source);
}
```

And then, cast where appropriate;

```
foreach (Person e in list.People.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(Employee)))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(((Employee)e).salary.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your particular example, the inheritance structure is not adding much benefit, but I digress.

In your example, the easiest solution would be to override the `ToString` method in each one of your classes.

Having to know the exact type of the object before hand before you run some sort of calculation or display puts the onus of that calculation onto the calling code, if you make a 3rd type, you would have to update all possible references, giving you a maintenance nightmare.

The feel the logic of how to represent itself should be the responsibility (in your example) of the object itself.

This is what overriding `ToString` gives you, the responsibility of representing itself is then given to the thing that knows best (the object you're asking).